# Populate form fields using json,php

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms

im having a problem populating form fields.

When choosing value from doropdown fields in first line input fields are populated , i have 5 fields that are populated from database. To get those values im using:
".select_ttl" is a dropdown name attribute.

```
$(".select_ttl").change(function(event){

            var kit=$(".select_ttl").val();
            $.getJSON('/getanimation.php?kit=' + kit, null,
            function(data)  
            {
                $("#kit").val(data.kit);
                $("#animation").val(data.animation);
                $("#prix").val(data.prix);

    });  
    });
```

the php file is:

```
<?php
require_once("inc/init.php");
require_once("inc/session.php");
require_once('inc/sql.php'); 
require_once("inc/config.ui.php");

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $title  = $_GET["kit"]; // we received this from the json call

    $Mysql = new Mysql();
    $array_action = $Mysql->TabResSQL("SELECT * FROM liste_animation inner join kit ON liste_animation.ID_LISTE_ANIMATION=kit.ID_LISTE_ANIMATION where kit.CODE='".$title."'  ");

foreach($array_action as $key){ 

    $data = array(
        'kit'            => $key->CODE,
        'animation'      => $key->NOM_ANIMATION,
        'prix'           => $key->PRIX_ANIMATEUR,

    );
    }



    echo (json_encode($data));

?>
```

Using this code i get only values for one row, in form there is an option to add a new line of input fields. So mu problem is how to do the same for multiple lines? Thanks in advance.

This is form example:

```
<div class="form-inline col-xs-2">
            <select class="select_ttl form-control" name="kit" id="kit">
              <option class='select_ttl' value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Kit</option>


 <?php 
                $Mysql = new Mysql();
                $ArraySelect = $Mysql->TabResSQL('SELECT distinct KIT from kit_voyage');


                foreach($ArraySelect as $key){ 
              echo "<option value=".$key->KIT.">".$key->KIT."</option>";

          ?>

        <?php } ?>
            </select> <!-- end .select_ttl -->
          </div>
        <!-- Text input-->

        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">

          <input id="animation" name="animation" type="text" placeholder="nom animation" class="input_fn form-control" required="" value=''>

        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->

        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">

          <input  id="prix" name="prix" type="text" placeholder="PU_HT" class="input_ln form-control" value=''>
        </div>    
        <!-- Text input--> 

        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">

          <input value="1" id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text" placeholder="qtité" class="input_email form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">

          <input id="tva" name="tva" type="text" placeholder="TVA" class="input_email form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">

          <input id="rem" name="rem" type="text" placeholder="REM" class="input_email form-control">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">

          <input id="totaltt" name="totaltt" type="text" placeholder="Total TT" class="input_email form-control">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 $(".select_ttl").change(function(event){
        var kit=$(this).val();
    });
```

& insted of `echo (json_encode($data));` use `echo json_encode($data);` remove outter `()`

Comment: I did like that, and it shows data for first line, but for the second one it doesn't show anything.